# Is there a way to interact with the image in ROS RViz?

Tags: ros

For people who have experience with ROS RViz, I am showing an image in an image pane.

Is there a way that I can interact with it? Zoom it? Maximize the window?

Answer (score 0):

**Is there a way to interact with the image?**

No, because RViz is just a visualization tool rather than a simulator with physics engine (e.g., Gazebo). In RViz, it will display whatever data it receives. **This is a one-direction data streaming** and no feedback will be sent back. Therefore, if you expect something like the robot can move to some point after you click it in the image, this is not doable (at least not by its default image pane).

There is another way to interact with the robot if needed, which is to use the [dynamic reconfiguration](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure). The setup is a kind of similar to how you create a customized ROS message or service. With this, you can change the parameters (via GUI, like to drag on a bar) when the robot is moving (instead of using the static parameters loaded before launching the robot). Note that this GUI will send the new parameters via ROS message in the backend, so this is a **bidirectional communication**.

**Can we zoom the image?**

If the pane is fixed and you only want to zoom the image, then no, because again it can only display whatever it receives in the fixed-size pane.

**Can we maximize the window?**

Yes, you can do this by dragging the window frame, and the image will adjust its display size accordingly.

Also, if you want to keep the window at a larger size, you can save the configuration as a `.rviz` file and launch RViz as shown in the following.

```
<node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find package_name)/rviz/config.rviz" />
```

You can either manually adjust the window and save it, or open the `.rviz` file you just created, look up for the window size and change it to the number you want.